# Skip M elements and Delete N elements from LinkedList, skipping 0 raising issue

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

My Algo-

```
private static MyList skip$DeleteItem(MyList L , int M , int N){
    MyList curr = L;
    MyList prev = null;
    while(curr != null){
        int counter = 0;
        while(curr != null && counter <M){
            prev = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
            counter++;
        }
        counter = 0;
        while(curr != null && counter < N){
            curr = curr.next;
            if(prev == null){                   
                prev = curr;
            }
            else{               
            prev.next = curr;
            }               
            counter ++;
        }
    }

    return L;
}
```

It is working for every basic test case , but for skip value 0 and delete 1 is failing.

Input - 9-->34-->8-->7-->5-->4-->6-->3-->1-->2-->TAIL

Ouput - 9-->34-->TAIL

Expected - NULL ( as all elements should be deleted)

Solution was

```
while(curr != null && counter < N){     
                curr = curr.next;
                if(prev == null){                   
                    curr = curr.next;
                    L = curr;
                }
                else{               
                prev.next = curr;
                }               
                counter ++;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "skipping" part seems to be ok, but the deleting part is problematic.

```
while(curr != null && counter < N){
        curr = curr.next;
        if(prev == null){                   
            prev = curr;
        }
        else{               
        prev.next = curr;
        }               
        counter ++;
    }
```

On the first iteration, you first advance the curr pointer to the next element, and then,  `if(prev == null)` you advance prev to the same curr.

So in your example, at the end of the first iteration both curr and prev point to 34.
form then on, the rest of the list will be deleted properly.